# Simple C caclulator using getchar() - second operand is not totaling right

Tags: c, getchar

My professor wanted us to create a calculator that takes two positive operands and a single operator. Any spaces the user enters should be ignored.

the problem child I am having with this code is

```
else if (symbolRead == 1 && isNumber(ch)) {

num2 += (num2 * 10) + (ch - '0');
}
```

if i enter 55 + 66, I instead get 55 + 72. This might have something to do with ascii. 6 is 54 in ascii but i don't see at all how 6 += (6 * 10) + (54 - '0') yields 72.

Here is some error checking i did

Please enter a simple arithmetic expression:     55 +   66

before add: num1 is 0

after add: num1 is 5

before add: num1 is 5

after add: num1 is 55

before add: num2 is 0

after add: num2 is 6

before add: num2 is 6

after add: num2 is 72

I want to note that if I did, say, 55 + 7, i WILL get the correct answer so It's got something to do with the way num2 is adding the next digit. I know the code has got some other problems but it's relatively done once i figure out why this is happening. Your help is much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addition(num1, num2);
int subtraction(num1, num2);
float division(num1, num2);
int multiply(num1, num2);
int modulus(num1, num2);

//functions made to act like isdigit, ispunct, and isspace
int isNumber(int chara);
int isSymbol(char chara);
int isASpace(int chara);

int main() {

    int ch, num1 = 0, num2 = 0, goAgain = 1, result = 0;
    char symbol = 0;
    int symbolRead = 0;
    int error = 0;

    printf("Welcome to simple calculator simulator.\nPlease enter a simple arithmetic expression: ");
    do {
        while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
            if (isASpace(ch)) {
                continue;
            }
            else if (!isNumber(ch) && !isSymbol(ch)) {
                printf("ERRORr: %d is not a valid input", ch);
                error = 1;
            }   //error checking

            if (error == 0) {
                if (symbolRead == 0 && isNumber(ch)) {
                    num1 = (num1 * 10) + (ch - '0');
                }
                else if (symbolRead == 1 && isNumber(ch)) {
                    num2 += (num2 * 10) + (ch - '0');
                }
                else if (isSymbol(ch)) {
                    symbol = ch;
                    symbolRead++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (symbolRead > 1) {
            printf("ERROR: More than one symbol detected. Please try again using only positive integers.");
            error = 1;
        }
        if (error == 0) {
            switch (symbol) {
            case '+':
                printf("You have selected addition. Calculating your result...\n");
                result = addition(num1, num2);
                printf("%d + %d = %d", num1, num2, result);

                break;
            case '-':
                printf("You have selected subtraction. Calculating your result...\n");
                result = subtraction(num1, num2);
                printf("%d - %d = %d", num1, num2, result);
                break;
            case '/':
                printf("You have selected integer division. Calculating your result...\n");
                result = division(num1, num2);
                printf("%d / %d = %d", num1, num2, result);
                break;
            case '*':
                printf("You have selected multiplication. Calculating your result...\n");
                result = multiply(num1, num2);
                printf("%d * %d = %d", num1, num2, result);
                break;
            case '%':
                printf("You have selected modulus divison. Calculating your result...\n");
                result = modulus(num1, num2);
                printf("%d %% %d = %d", num1, num2, result);
                break;
            }

        }
        printf("\nWould you like to try another expression? 1 for yes and 0 for no: ");
        scanf("%d", &goAgain);

    } while (goAgain == 1);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int isASpace(int chara) {
    if (chara == ' ' || chara == '\t')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
int isNumber(int chara) {
    if (chara >= 48 && chara <=57)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
int isSymbol(char chara) {
    if (chara == '*' || chara == '%' || chara == '+' || chara == '/' || chara == '-')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
int addition(num1, num2) {
    return (num1 + num2);
}
int subtraction(num1, num2) {
    return (num1 - num2);
}
float division(num1, num2) {
    return (num1 / num2);
}
int multiply(num1, num2) {
    return (num1 * num2);
}
int modulus(num1, num2) {
    return (num1 % num2);
}
```

Comment: I cannot actually believe I missed that. Holy CRAP. thank you!

Comment: I think you should store digits (from input) into two temp arrays (in each-store data till you encounter non-numerical character), then use `atoi` and store the integer output into two integer variable & then use them for operations - that will be simpler.

Comment: My professor is extremely picky with what he wants and arrays are not something he would allow. All functions have to be made ourselves. But yes I agree that sounds a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The problem was due to a minor syntax error:

num2 += (num2 * 10) + (ch - '0')

vs.

num2 = (num2 * 10) + (ch - '0')